# Why do these Print Statements Come Out Different?

Tags: java

```
String test = (String)String.valueOf(((char) 0 + 65));
System.out.println( test);
test = "A"; 
System.out.println(test);
```

The first one produces 65, the other produces A. They should produce the same thing.

Answer (score 4):

You do it in the wrong order. First you cast zero to `char` and the you add 65 which is an implicit cast to `int`. You first need to add the values and then do the cast.

```
 String test = String.valueOf((char)( 0 + 65));
```

Then your code produce the expected result:

```
A
A
```

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the operator precedence (of casting, relative to addition) not being what you expect.

You expect `0 + 65` to happen first, and *then* for the result to be cast to a char.  However, the cast binds more tightly than addition, so `(char) 0` happens first, and then it is added to 65.

Since this is two numbers being added together, the result is a numeric 65, and this is what gets converted into a String (so results in the two character string `['6', '5']`.

You can make the casting happen later with brackets around the arithmetic expression:

```
String.valueOf((char)(0 + 65))
```

Answer (score 0):

The first expression is the same as

```
(char) 0 + 65
```

is

```
`\0` + 65
```

which is

```
(int) `\0` + 65
```

or

```
65
```

This is because casting takes precedence.

To get a char type and `A` you need to cast after you do the calculation

```
char ch = (char) (0 + 65)
System.out.println(ch);
```